# Attributes of Swap Partition

Tags: security, swap, timestamps, hashsum, hibernate

I'm doing some research in security of Linux-based OS. Specially, I'm trying to understand the structure of Linux (non-crypto) Swap file / Swap partition. For my research, I use Linux Ubuntu 16.04 x64.

Does anybody knows something about mechanisms of integrity assurance of Swap partition?

Now, when I change some of bytes in Swap partirion of Hibernated System (total length is the same!) with powered-off system and save changes, Linux trying to start system from Hibernation and can't apply my changes. Looks like start not from Hibernation, but like start "from zero", from powered-off clear system.
Maybe, Swap Partition has hash-based summary, or some attributes with changed_time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369386/structure-of-swap-partition, asked by the same person.

Comment: Please to not ask the same question in rapid succession.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, I disagree with You. When I asked 2 questions at one time at askubuntu. they asked me to separate questions and post it on  Unix & Linux. First time in my questions is the same, because it is preamble

Comment: I also believe that these are not the same question. The other one is asking, in general, about the layout / structure of the swap area; this one is asking about mechanisms in Linux to detect tampering with the swap area. These are about as different as asking for the recipe for peanut butter and asking about the tamper-evident seal that they put across the top of the jar, under the lid.

Comment: @DopeGhoti the questions are not even similar, really. They just happen to have the same introductory paragraph, but they are asking for completely different things. The other is asking for documentation, so it is off topic anyway.